# How to run a downloaded pip package?

Tags: python, pip

I recently coded a pygame and made it into an installable pip package. It is on the python package index and I installed it using pip install. How do I access the files or run the program?

pyproject.toml

```
   [build-system]
   requires = ["setuptools>=42", "wheel"]
   build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

setup.cfg

```
[metadata]
name = filled
version = filled
author = filled
author_email = filled
description = A program to help you solve wordle games!
long_description = file: README.md
long_description_content_type = text/markdown
url = https://github.com/filled
classifiers =
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3
    License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License
    Operating System :: OS Independent

[options]
packages = find:
python_requires = >=3.6
include_package_data = True
```

Comment: How did you run the program before? What build back-end does it use (setuptools or something else)? Edit your question to show more details (`pyproject.toml`, `setup.cfg`, `setup.py`, etc.).

Comment: okay I edited it for those two files I have. I just followed a tutorial on YouTube to get everything set up. whenever I do pip list it shows up in the list. should I have created an executable in it that people can run or something. I want to make it very easy for people to use my program

Comment: You probably want to define some "console script entry point": https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/entry_point.html

Answer (score 0):

That depends on a few things.

1. Are you using a venv?
2. What OS are you using?

If you are using virtual enviornment:

```
path = `{virtual env}/lib/site-packages/{your package}`
```

If you are using a linux OS and using a local profile.

```
path = `~/.local/lib/python{version number}/site-packages/{your package}`
```

if you are on windows its usually something like

```
path = `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\local\Programs\Python\Python{version number}\Lib\site-packages\{your package}`
```

I am not sure about Mac.  Maybe someone else can answer that one.

Comment: I am using both mac and windows. I uploaded the package on windows. Maybe I typed it in wrong or something but the windows path that you put doesn't work. I wasn't in any specific directory whenever I pip installed if that helps.

Comment: On windows an easy way to find it is to open up file explorer and search for site-packages

Answer (score 0):

example:

```bash
python -m package_name
```